# VBA .SendUsingAccount doesn't work on every PC

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a tool that sends emails using vba and .SendUsingAccount functionality. We have a team of people that use shared Email-Account and the tool works for most of us, but there is at least one person that get an error in the ".SendUsingAccount" line. When I delete this line, the tool works correctly, with the one difference: it sends an email from the private email via Outlook of course, and not from the team Email-Account.

Is there any reason, maybe something with private Excel options, that make the tool crash for one user, but still working find for the others?

Comment: To the ones where everything works as expected have more accounts in Outlook? Does the code define `SendUsingAccount` before using it? I mean, an iteration inside `Session.Accounts` (for each `oAccount`) should be done and, creating an `oMail` item and according to some criteria, to finally `Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount`. And only after that use `oMail.Send`.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook appears the same whether there are multiple accounts or one account and multiple mailboxes.

[Add an email account to Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b).

[image]

Comment: This is interesting! So the person shouldn't use one account with multiple mailboxes but add an account for every mailbox?

Comment: If `.SendUsingAccount` is needed that is a start. With any luck it will be the end as well.